How to put a focus inside a method in wpf using c#?
I am trying to implement using a Focus but notice i a missing something, but if i am using it on xaml.cs its working fine. What approach must i use to accomplish this on the method on a class?
`public void SaveTicket()
{
    try

    {

        // Check if the compartment selected is "truck-empty" and the purpose is "Leaving-Finished Product"
        if (View.comboCompartment.SelectedItem != null && Convert.ToInt32(View.comboCompartment.SelectedValue)== 6)
            
            
        {
            // Check if TopSeal is empty
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(View.Topseal.Trim()))
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("TopSeal cannot be empty", "Validation Error");
                Topseal.Focus(); // problem is here. What can i use here in order for Focus to be recognised by intellisense?
                return;
            }

            // Check if BottomSeal is empty
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(View.BottomSeal.Trim()))
            {
               System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("BottomSeal cannot be empty", "Validation Error");
                
                return;
            }
        }
}`


Please post some part of Xaml code
